# Return JSON array with name from WCF with service

Tags: wcf

I am able to return an JSON arrray from a WCF rest service.

```
[ {"Name" : "john", "age" : 23 }, {"Name" : "Petter",  "age" : 21 } ]
```

but how can I add a name to the array. In this case, I want to add the "People" to the beginning of the array

```
{"People" : [ {"Name" : "john", "age" : 23 }, {"Name" : "Petter",  "age" : 21 } ]}
```

Comment: What language are you using to generate the JSON string? Ideally you would change the object to what you want *before* converting it to a JSON string.

Comment: It's WCF, so C# or VB.NET are your most likely candidates

Comment: How are you returning JSON like this: `[ {"Name" : "john", "age" : 23 }, {"Name" : "Petter",  "age" : 21 } ]`? I'm having the opposite problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073866/generate-json-array-with-wcf#comment12896252_10073866

Answer (score 0, accepted):

return an object that has a people field whose value is an array of your name/age objects.

For example

```
[DataContract]
public class People
{
    [DataMember]
    public Person[] People { get; set; }
}
```

This assumes Person is the class you're returning in your array, for example:

```
[DataContract]
public class Person
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can't believe it is so easy :)

Comment: I just noticed that I left out the name of the property. that's fixed

Answer (score 3):

The easy way is change `BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare` to `BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped`.

The [`Wrapped` enum member](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webmessagebodystyle.aspx) does it for you.

Comment: It works for me. Can you tell me how can I change json array name? Right now I get: {"WcfMethodName":[....]}.