# Returning JSON Array in WCF

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services

In PHP I can do this for example:

```
while($r = mssql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
   $rowsField["rowsinfo"][] = $r;
}

print json_encode($rowsField);
```

Which basically returns a (two/multi dimensional I believe) array and returns it in a JSON format.

I am trying to achieve the same thing as I am moving my website to .NET.

So I am trying to do this in a WCF Web Service and so far I have only had success getting this far with Newtonsoft JSON Converter.

I managed to return a DataTable in JSON format but I now need it to return almost like the array like: `[["rowsinfo"]{"Address":"15 Tyne Cresent","Name":"John Smith"}]`  etc...

How can this be achieved? Is it a DataTable I need to return still?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you'd find this interesting:
[C# WCF REST client JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514063/c-sharp-wcf-rest-client-json-array)
or [Generate JSON array with WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073866/generate-json-array-with-wcf)

Looks like there are a lot of questions about it already where you could potentially find more information.

Answer (score 0):

return this `List<string, List<string>()>()`

or just the multidimensional array

```
string[,] array = new string[4, 2];
```

Comment: Will this work if I don't know what columns I will be displaying from the database? Basically, the SQL Query that is executed is dynamic so will not always return the same data

Comment: Hmm yes, it that is the case, I just edited my answer

Comment: hmm, it doesn't seem to like this. How would I then add my SQL results to this list? Thanks!